# Array Index out of bounds for Java using terminal

Tags: java, arrays, file, exception, parameter-passing

I am having trouble with a ticketing system that I am trying to create using java. I am trying to utilize two files to read and write my inputs. I am testing with just salesSell method at the moment. I am passing the args using terminal. The problem that I am having is an arrayoutofbounds exception that gets thrown.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 at cisc_327_frontend.Frontend_try1.main(Frontend_try1.java:763)
```

the two array parameters that I am passing are parsed from the same line in my current events file. an example of a line in the file is : "testevent1__________0003". I cannot seem to figure out where I am having this problem. Any type of guidance would be much appreciated.

```
package cisc_327_frontend;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Frontend_try1 {

private static File fileOutput;
private static List<StringBuilder> eventTrans = new ArrayList<>();


public static void consoleInput(String[] namesArray, int[] ticketArray,File fileCurrentEvents){
    System.out.println("Enter command:");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String inputString = input.nextLine();


    boolean correct = true;

        do{

            if(inputString.toUpperCase().equals( "LOGIN")) {
                //enter login mode
                login(namesArray, ticketArray,fileCurrentEvents);
                correct = true;

                }
            if(inputString.toUpperCase().equals("LOGOUT")){
                logout(namesArray, ticketArray,fileCurrentEvents);
                correct=true;
            }
                if (!"LOGIN".toUpperCase().equals(inputString) || !"LOGOUT".toUpperCase().equals(inputString)){
                    System.out.println("Incorrect command, please enter command:");
                    input = new Scanner(System.in);
                    inputString = input.nextLine();
                    correct = false;
                }

        }while(!correct);



    }

public static void login(String[] namesArray, int[] ticketArray,File fileCurrentEvents) {
    System.out.println("Sales or Admin?");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String inputString = input.nextLine();


    boolean correct = true ;

    do {
        if(inputString.toUpperCase().equals("LOGOUT")){
            logout(null, null, null);

        }
        else if(inputString.toUpperCase().equals("SALES")) {
            //enter sales mode
            sales(namesArray, ticketArray,fileCurrentEvents);
            correct = true;
        } else if (inputString.toUpperCase().equals("ADMIN")) {
            //enter admin mode
            admin(namesArray, ticketArray,fileCurrentEvents);
            correct = true;
        } else if (inputString.toUpperCase().equals("LOGOUT")) {
            //enter logout mode
            logout( namesArray, ticketArray, fileCurrentEvents);
            correct = true;
        } else  {
            //ask again
            System.out.println("Invalid Input");
            System.out.println("Sales or Admin?");
            input = new Scanner(System.in);
            inputString = input.nextLine();
            correct = false;
        }

    }while(!correct);

}

public static void sales(String[] namesArray, int[] ticketArray,File fileCurrentEvents) {
    //System.out.println("SALES");
    System.out.println("Sales Mode");
    System.out.println("Enter Command:");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String inputString = input.nextLine();


    boolean correct = true ;

    do {
        if(inputString.toUpperCase().equals("LOGOUT")){
            logout( namesArray, ticketArray, fileCurrentEvents);

        }
        else if(inputString.toUpperCase().equals("SELL")) {
            //enter sales Sell mode
            salesSell(namesArray, ticketArray,fileCurrentEvents);
            correct = true;
        } else if (inputString.toUpperCase().equals("RETURN")) {
            //enter sales Return mode
            salesReturn(namesArray, ticketArray,fileCurrentEvents);
            correct = true;
        } else if (inputString.toUpperCase().equals("LOGOUT")) {
            //enter Logout mode
            logout( namesArray, ticketArray, fileCurrentEvents);
            correct = true;
        } else {
            //ask again
            System.out.println("Invalid Input");
            System.out.println("Enter Command:");
            input = new Scanner(System.in);
            inputString = input.nextLine();
            correct = false;
        }

    }while(!correct);



}


public static void salesSell(String[] namesArray, int[] ticketArray,File fileCurrentEvents) {
    int index = 0;
    String eventName = null;
    int numberTickets = 0;
    System.out.println("Sales Sell Mode");

    System.out.println("What is the name of your event?");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String inputString = input.nextLine();

    if(inputString.toUpperCase().equals("LOGOUT")){
        logout( namesArray, ticketArray, fileCurrentEvents);

    }

    try{

        for(int i = 0; i < namesArray.length; i++) {
            if(namesArray[i].equals(inputString)){
                index = i;
            }
        }
         eventName= namesArray[index];
          numberTickets=ticketArray[index] ;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error: Event not found within file");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    int event = inputString.length();
    boolean charnumber = true;

    do{
        if(inputString.toUpperCase().equals("LOGOUT")){
            logout( namesArray, ticketArray, fileCurrentEvents);

        }
    if(event< 0 || event >20){

        System.out.println("No more than 20 characters allowed for name!");
        System.out.println("Enter name:");
        input = new Scanner(System.in);
        inputString = input.nextLine();
        event=inputString.length();
        charnumber = false;
    }
    else{
        charnumber = true;

    }

    } while(!charnumber);


    System.out.println("How many tickets?");
    input = new Scanner(System.in);
    inputString = input.nextLine();
    int digit;


    while(true){
    try {
        digit = Integer.parseInt(inputString);

    break;
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e){


    }


    System.out.println("Please type a number!");    
    inputString = input.nextLine(); 
    }

if( numberTickets - digit <0){
    System.out.println("Illegal amount of tickets! Buy less ticket please.");

}
else{
    int tickets = numberTickets - digit;

    ticketArray[index]=tickets;


}
    boolean dignumber = true;

    do{
        if(inputString.toUpperCase().equals("LOGOUT")){
            logout( namesArray, ticketArray, fileCurrentEvents);

        }
    if(digit<0 || digit>8){

        System.out.println("Only 8 tickets allowed to be sold!");
        inputString = input.nextLine();
        event=inputString.length();

        dignumber = false;
        digit= Integer.parseInt(inputString);
    }
    else{
        dignumber= true;

    }
    }while(!dignumber);

}




public static boolean logout(String[] namesArray, int[] ticketArray,File fileCurrentEvents) {
    FileWriter logoutFileWriter;
    FileWriter currEventsFileWriter;
    int numSpaces = 0;

    try{
        currEventsFileWriter = new FileWriter(fileCurrentEvents, true);

            for(int i = 0; i < namesArray.length; i++ ) {
                currEventsFileWriter.write(namesArray[i]);
                numSpaces = 20 - (namesArray[i].length() + 4);
                for(int j = 0; j < numSpaces; j++) {
                    currEventsFileWriter.write("_");
                }
                currEventsFileWriter.write(ticketArray[i]);
                currEventsFileWriter.write(String.format("%n"));
            }       

    } catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Rewriting Current Events File Error");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    try {
        logoutFileWriter = new FileWriter(fileOutput, true);

        //Cycle through event trans file and write via filewriter
        for(int i = 0; i < eventTrans.size(); i++ ) {
            String transact = eventTrans.get(i).toString();
            logoutFileWriter.write(transact);
            logoutFileWriter.write(String.format("%n"));
        }
        // Signify end of file
        logoutFileWriter.write("00                       000000 00000");
        logoutFileWriter.write(String.format("%n"));
        logoutFileWriter.close();
        fileOutput.createNewFile();

    } catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Output File Error");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    return true;

    /*
    for( int i = 0; i < 20; i++ ) {
        System.out.println("");
    }
    System.out.println("Logged Out");
    consoleInput();
*/
}



public static void main(String[] args){

    try {
        File fileCurrentEvents = new File(args[0]);
        fileOutput = new File(args[1]);

        // Read current events file for events & dates
        FileReader fileRead = new FileReader(fileCurrentEvents);
        BufferedReader buffRead = new BufferedReader(fileRead);

        // Create strings for data in current events file
        String currentLine;
        String eventName;
        Integer numberTickets;
        List<Integer> numticket = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        int[] numarray= new int[numticket.size()];
        String[] linesArray = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
        // Cycle through current events file line by line
        while((currentLine = buffRead.readLine()) != null) {
            if (currentLine.equals("END_________________00000")){
                break; // End of file
            }

            //Parse for event name & number of tickets
            eventName = currentLine.substring(0, currentLine.lastIndexOf("_")).trim();
            numberTickets = Integer.parseInt(currentLine.substring(currentLine.lastIndexOf
                    ("_") + 1));



            // Place event name and # tickets into data structure
            // Add event name to event array list with same index as # tickets
            // Parse int to get # tickets & add to arraylist for tickets with same index


             while((eventName = buffRead.readLine()) != null){
                   list.add(eventName);
                }


                for (int i =0 ; i< list.size();i++){

                    linesArray[i]= list.get(i);

                }




                 while((eventName = buffRead.readLine()) != null){
                       numticket.add(numberTickets);
                    }


                    for (int i =0 ; i< numticket.size();i++){

                        numarray[i]= numticket.get(i);

                    }

        }

        while(true) {
            consoleInput(linesArray, numarray, fileCurrentEvents);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("File I/O Error"); //Print to console to signify error
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }



}

}
```

Comment: TOO...MUCH....CODE...can you narrow down your question?

Comment: `ticketArray[0]` must be throwing the exception if the array is empty, on this line: `ticketArray[index]=tickets;`

Comment: What line does it say the error is being thrown on?

Comment: the error is being thrown on this line in the main method. " File fileCurrentEvents = new File(args[0]);" @TotZam

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i trimmed my code

Comment: post the error please

Comment: How are running the program, or what is you command line code or IDE settings? It sounds likes you are aren't giving any arguments.

Comment: "java -jar quib.jar Current_Events_File.txt Output_File.txt"     is what i use to pass it. I pass it using terminal bash script. @Linus

Comment: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
 at cisc_327_frontend.Frontend_try1.main(Frontend_try1.java:763)"  is the error message that i get @RossDrew

Comment: Not your problem, but I think you need to learn about [`String.equalsIgnoreCase(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase-java.lang.String-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting an `ArrayOutOfBoundsIndexException` at this line

```
File fileCurrentEvents = new File(args[0]);
```

Then it probably means the *array* (`args`) *index* (`0`) you are using is *out of bounds* in that it is higher than the size of the array.

If you have an array that looks like

```
 [] //Zero entries
```

You can't get element `0` (the first item), because there are none.

So you must be passing in zero parameters when you run the code.  Either when you run it at the command line, add the filename after it or change the build settings in your IDE (Eclipse, IntelliJ, Sublime) to add it to the build steps.

Answer (score 0):

> the error is being thrown on this line in the main method. `File fileCurrentEvents = new File(args[0]);`

Then your `args` is empty (e.g. you haven't run your program with any command line arguments, like a file). You could add a default, something like

```
File fileCurrentEvents = new File(args.length > 0 ? args[0] : "default.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

In your original code, line 763 is actually:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i< list.size(); i++){

   linesArray[i] = list.get(i); //<--------------THIS ONE!

}
```

which can cause an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when `linesArray` is shorter that `list`. This is happening because you instantiated `linesArray` earlier via

```
 String[] linesArray = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
```

when `list` was empty, then added to `list` making it longer than your array.

Since the outer while-loop doesn't appear to use the `linesArray` in any other capacity, you can probably remove the above for-loop and, and place

```
 linesArray = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
```

after the first while loop to create the appropriate array with all the elements.